# Override html.tpl.php per node type

Tags: 7, theming

In my template.php file for my theme I have tried the following:

```
function media_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) 
  {
      // If the node type is "blog" the template suggestion will be "html--blog.tpl.php".
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__'.$vars['node']->type;

      // If the node type is "blog" the template suggestion will be "page--blog.tpl.php".
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'.$vars['node']->type;

      // If the node id is "33" the template suggestion will be "page--33.tpl.php".
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'.$vars['node']->nid;    
  }

    //Create page suggestion for first part of url-alias
    $url_alias = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
    $parts = explode('/', $url_alias);

    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'.$parts[0].'__alias';  
}
```

This works for page--nodetype.tpl.php, but not for html--nodetype.tpl.php

You may be asking why do you need to override the html.tpl.php template per node type. It is because there is markup that I don't want to include for this particular node.

Answer (score 29):

The name of a preprocess function is based on the theme/template that is being processed. To preprocess the html.tpl.php file you'll need to use `hook_preprocess_html()`:

```
function media_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $node = menu_get_object();

  if ($node && $node->nid) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__' . $node->type;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@Clive approach is very smart.

Also do note when in  html.tpl.php file, you can read the content type you are dealing with from `$variables['classes']`, which will give you something like `html not-front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-node page-node- page-node-5638 node-type-CONTENT-TYPE-NAME`

With that, you can change how html.tpl.php file is behaving with this:

```
if (strpos($variables['classes'],'node-type-YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE') == true ) {
  echo 'Do something special  for YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE ';
}
```