# Custom html.tpl.php from module for custom type

Tags: 7, theming

I have built a module that adds a new custom content type.
I need to use my own html.tpl.php for that content type, and the html template sits on my module folder.

I have done somee xperiments, I was able to replace the template of the node content, but it's not enough, and I can't seem to find some examples or explanatory documentation about it.

If my module is called "tomato" and my custom type is called "sauce", and I already have a file called html--sauce.tpl.php on my module folder, how do I tell Drupal to use that template when a "sauce" node is loaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override html.tpl.php per node type](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21751/override-html-tpl-php-per-node-type)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, the other one is for a theme, I need it for a module, I tried the theme road, it does not work on module.

Comment: I guess it wasn't obvious from the other question that `hook_preprocess_html()` can be used in module's. Answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules can use `hook_preprocess_html()` to override theme templates. You need 3 things:

- A [`hook_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) implementation
- A [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) implementation
- A html template in your module dir

Using a module called `MYMODULE`, with a new node type `mynodetype`, & a template in the module dir named **templates/html--mynodetype.tpl.php**, we can add the following hooks to `MYMODULE`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $node = menu_get_object();

  // Add a new theme suggestion when viewing node's of mynodetype.
  if ($node && $node->nid && $node->type == 'mynodetype') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__mynodetype';
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $theme = array();

  //Add our templates/html--mynodetype.tpl.php to the theme registry
  $theme['html__mynodetype'] = array(
    'template' => 'html--mynodetype',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/templates',
  );
  return $theme;
}
```